# Pino unable to determine transport target on Nextjs

Tags: typescript, next.js, pinojs

On my next js app, I'm trying to use pino (v 8.7.0) where I want to log client to a file. I tried following their [documentation](https://getpino.io/#/docs/transports?id=transports) on transports, but I had no success. I get an eror message saying

```
Error: unable to determine transport target for "some-file-transport.log"
```

My code is as follows:
pino-logger-service.ts

```
import pino, { default as Pino } from 'pino';

export const initLogger = () => {
  const pinoLogger = Pino( {
    serialize: true,
    formatters: {
      level (label) {
        return { level: label }
      }
    },
    browser: {
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
      write: (obj: any) => {
        console.log(`${JSON.stringify(obj)}`);
      }
    }
  });

  const transport = pino.transport({
    target: 'some-file-transport.log',
    options: { destination: '../logs' }
  })
  pino(transport)
  return pinoLogger;
};
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you manage to solve it ?

Comment: I haven't been able to.

Comment: target should be pino/file as that is the transport type in effect, So your destination should include the file name e.g. ../logs/some-file-transport.log